# cast an object to an interface in java?

Tags: java, interface

if we cast an object to an interface, won't this object be able to call its own methods? in the following example, `myObj` will only be able to call MyInterface methods?

```
MyInterface myObj = new Obj();
```

If this is correct, what is the difference between those 2 objects :

```
MyInterface myObj = new Obj();

MyInterface mySec = new Sec();
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) might be of help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
MyInterface myObj = new Obj(); 
MyInterface mySec = new Sec();
```

For this to be legal, both `Obj` and `Sec` will have to be implementers of `MyInterface`. The difference between these two objects would be *how* they provide that implementation. `Obj` and `Sec` could do two very different or very similar things, but their commonality is that they would adhere to a contract that you could rely upon. Consider you have a method

```
public void doSomethingWith(MyInterface thing) {
     thing.frob();
}
```

Each object, `myObj` and `mySec`, could be passed into this method, and this method could then use that object's `frob` method (assuming frob is part of the interface declaration). This is *liberating*. This allows you to do very powerful things, by programming to interfaces and not to implementations. For example, you can extend functionality of classes and not change a line of code in those classes, you simply pass a different implementation of a dependency. You are not tied to, or *coupled with*, any one implentation inside the method `doSomethingWith`.

> but i also read that if we declare the object myObj as MyInterface,
>   myObj won't be able to use its own methods (from the class Obj), is
>   that correct

Internally, instances of `Obj` will continue to have full access to the `Obj` API. `myObj` is still an `Obj`, it will always be able to use its own implementation details.

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void frob();
}

public class Obj implements MyInterface {

    public void frob() {
        doFrobbing();
    }

    private void doFrobbing() {
        System.out.println("frobbing");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyInterface myObj = new Obj();
        myObj.frob(); // still internally calls doFrobbing()
        ((Obj)myObj).doFrobbing(); // visible only via class reference
    }
}
```

Instances of `Obj` will still be instances of `Obj`, and those instances will still be able to use `doFrobbing`. Externally, persons *using* those instances via the interface reference will only be able to access the interface methods.

Comment: thanks anthony for this great explanation, i understand this, and even more now thanks, but i also read that if we declare the object `myObj` as MyInterface, `myObj` won't be able to use its own methods (from the class `Obj`), is that correct?

Comment: thanks for the update, so what's the point to do this? (hiding the `Obj`'s methods when `MyInterface` is the type) An interface "exists" in order to "add" some methods to an object, right?, so why does it hide the other methods? (or maybe there are no reasons for that, this works because, as a general rule in every programming language, a "type" works like that?)

Comment: It goes back to programming against the interface. Remember, when you write a method like `doSomethingWith(MyInterface thing)`, you simply *do not care* what *else* `Obj` can do! You're only interested in the fact that it can `frob()`. `Obj` itself cares about its own implementation. Code dependent directly upon `Obj` obviously cares about what `Obj` can do. But code that depends upon the interface only needs to worry about the interface. Not really sure how to phrase it to make it click, but hopefully it does.

Comment: Looking at it further, say you're inside `doSomethingWith` and you're dealing with `thing`. What would you expect to see in `thing`? You obviously couldn't look for Obj's API, you have no way of knowing you are dealing with Obj. You can't look for Sec for the very same reason. The only API *you know about* is the API for `MyInterface`. It is *that* API that you depend upon. Other methods elsewhere might depend upon other parts of Obj's API, interface-defined or otherwise. But here, we only care about the API as defined by MyInterface.

Comment: first thanks for your answer, let's say : we started a project without interfaces, and then we want to implement an interface because we need more methods to be added on my objects (in my first post : `myObj` and `mySec`) : so we will lose the previous methods from Obj and Sec because we will declare `myObj`and `mySec` as `MyInterface`'s objects... so we'll need to change all the code, because MyInterface does not contain the methods from my objets Classes

Comment: Those methods are not lost, not in the slightest. Now, while you're operating under the reference of the interface, the non-interface methods will not be *visible*, but that's not the same as *losing* the functionality. The issue I think you're running into is that you might be trying to use the interface when it's not warranted (you actually *need* to directly invoke the non-interface API in a given method), or maybe you have code that is dependent upon too much and is trying to do too much.

Comment: But remember, just because Obj implements MyInterface, you are not restricted to only ever referring to myObj via the interface. It simply allows you to use an instance of `Obj` somewhere that *needs* a `MyInterface`. That somewhere that *needs* the interface shouldn't care if its an Obj! If it *does* care, then it *needs* Obj, not MyInterface.

Comment: mmh okay, i think i have to look at some examples, but i think i've got it. Thanks Anthony, big discussion, but really thanks a lot, i really appreciated your help!

Answer (score 2):

Only the methods in the interface are **visible**, but all methods in the object may still be invoked, as long as they're made accessible otherwise.  For example:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    String getName();
}

public class Obj implements MyInterface {
    private String getFirstName() {
        return "John";
    }

    private String getLastName() {
        return "Doe";
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return getFirstName() + " " + getLastName();
    }
}

public class Sec implements MyInterface {
    private String getDate() {
        return new Date().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return getDate();
    }
}
```

In the above cases, both `Obj` and `Sec` can call their private members, even though they will not be visible in other classes.  So when you say...

```
MyInterface myObj = new Obj();
MyInterface mySec = new Sec();
```

...as you've asked in the question, while it is true that in `myObj` and `mySec` the only method visible is `getName()`, their underlying implementation can be different.

Comment: thanks jonathan for this great explanation, mmh, ok i understand it a bit more, so if `Obj`'s methods are not visible by other classes, in which case does it matter? (do you have a simple example?)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not certain I understand your question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. You will only be able to invoke `MyInterface` interface methods on `myObj` and `mySec`. Obviously your code will only compile if both `Obj` and `Sec` implement the `Myinterface` interface.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer, so here's the thing : what if we started the project without interfaces, and then we want to implement an interface because we need more methods to be added on classes `A` and `B` : we will lose the previous methods from `A` and `B` because we will declare `a` and `b` as I's objects...

Comment: @Paul Interfaces exist for a purpose of adding some common *interface* (or in other words a contract) to different classes and letting those classes actually implement the *functionality* according to the contract. You are not actually required to use interfaces if you want to add new methods to a class. Here is a plain definition of what an interface is: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Comment: thanks Strelok, my misunderstanding is about changing the "Type" of an object, and put the interface as the "Type", this would mean that the obj's methods are not "visible" anymore... which confuses me a bit. I've got the principle of interfaces though, i understand that interfaces are some methods that 2 classes will share, but what i'm not sure to understand is : if "Interface" is the type, the other methods from the myObj class won't be visible anymore

Answer (score 1):

Changing the type of a variable (i.e. a reference) does not change the object itself. An object can always call its own methods, no matter what the types of declared variables are that reference to it.

Comment: touches the fundamentals very well

Answer (score 1):

```
MyInterface myObj = new Obj();
MyInterface mySec = new Sec();
```

You declare an instance of a MyInterface named myObj.
You initialize it with new Obj(); which is authorized by the compiler if Obj implements MyInterface.
myObj can only call MyInterface methods obviously.
Same for the second line.

Here is a sample code to try:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]){
          A a = new A();
          a.say();
          a.a();

          B b = new B();
          b.say();
          b.b();

          I ia = new A();
          ia.say();
          ia.a(); // fail
    }

}

interface i {
    public void say();
}

class A implements i {
    public void say(){
        System.out.println("class A");
    }
    public void a(){
        System.out.println("method a");
    }
}

class B implements i {
    public void say(){
        System.out.println("class B");
    }
    public void b(){
        System.out.println("method b");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks kbdjockey for your answer : okay, but what if we started the project without interfaces, and then we want to implement an interface because we need more methods to be added on classes `A` and `B` : we will lose the previous methods from `A` and `B` because we will declare `a` and `b` as I's objects...

Comment: Just because `A` and `B` implement `I` doesn't mean you have to instantiate them as such.  You can still say `A myObj = new A()`, and access all methods of `A` (including those overriden from `I`).

Answer (score 0):

In the code you showed you never perform any casts.

A typical use of an interface is to define some methods which will be available, without caring about the concrete implementation.

A nice example of this are the listeners in the standard JDK. For example the `PropertyChangeListener`. This is an interface which defines a method which can be called when 'a property is changed'. A typical use of this interface is to attach it to a class which has properties, and this class will warn those listeners when one of its properties has changed.

The class does not care what those listeners will do. It only relies on the fact this `propertyChange` method will be present, and calls that method.

The class can only call this method on the listener, since it only knows about the method defined in the interface. If those listeners have other methods, they can call those methods themself, but that is only because they know they are more then the interface.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyInterface mi = new Obj();
mi.getInterfaceMethods(); (methods in the MyInterface)

if(mi instanceof Obj) {
     mi.getObjMethods(); (methods in the Obj)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple analogy:

Consider a Chef(Interface). And there are Chinese chef(classes) and American chef(classes). 
Now, there is a Hotel looking out to recruit a chef based on some eligibility criteria such as

- can cook Non-vegeterian
- can cook vegeterian
- have experience of 5 years

Here, the eligibility is the context within which the Chef type person is evaluated(Types functionality). Now, there may be cases where Chinese chef can also cook sea food , Italian dishes etc. so could be the case with American counterpart. All these may seem irrelevant to Hotel manager as he is only concerned with required criteria.

Chefs work in a hotel is analogous to Chef type object utilised in code. The obvious work would be to cook vegeterian and non-vegeterian food(criteria or interface methods). That does not mean that the Hotel cannot utilize the Chinese chef's sea food making skills.

It's just a matter of specifying what skills(functionality) the Hotel is looking for.

Hope you get the idea.