# How to cast an object to an interface?

Tags: java

I want to be able to cast an unknown object type to an interface, then call an interface method on the newly cast object. I used to do this when developing in C++ and it worked fine.

I have attempted to make the cast only to get a ClassCastException.

```
interface Interact {
    void interact();
}

class Item implements Interact {

    public void interact(){
        System.out.println("Interacted");
    }
}


//This is pseudo code. I understand that obj is null
Object obj;

Interact interactable = (Interact) obj;

//Now I can call interact's methods
interactable.interact();
```

Comment: When you get an exception during runtime, then you shouldn't truncate your object creation and say "this is pseudo code". You're cutting crucial information.

Comment: Better way: Interact myInteract = new Item(); no casting, no possible errors

Comment: follow the below link for more clarity https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408892/cast-an-object-to-an-interface-in-java

Comment: @Stultuske There are other classes that may implement interact that aren't items.

Comment: @Tom I don't see how that information is crucial. The error I am getting is due to the language not allowing me to cast from an object to an interface.

Comment: The language generally does when you're not doing it wrong. You're doing it wrong, hence the exception, but we can't tell you what you're doing wrong since you've hidden that information from us. You can check that it works by using `Object obj = new Item()` to test the approach.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. If `obj` is *genuinely* null, you won't get an exception. Currently you haven't provided code that will compile on its own, so we can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: (If `obj` were genuinely null, you'd get a `NullPointerException` on the last line instead.)

Comment: @Wyatt yeah, duh, but I can assure you, Object isn't one of them. The language does allow you to cast from an object to an interface, but only if it's actually an implementation of the interface, that's how it's designed, that's common sense.

Comment: ClassCastException contains information about real class you trying to cast. Check that that class implements your interface.

Comment: @Stultuske C++ use different kind of common sense, so be careful here :)

Comment: @Stultuske You say "well duh" as if it is obvious, but the reality seems that Java won't allow casting of an object to an interface. I shall update code to not be psuedo.

Comment: @Wyatt "the reality seems that Java won't allow casting of an object to an interface", no it doesn't seem like that, and it isn't like that. Your Object has to be declared as a type that implements said interface. Again, if you understand what interfaces are, this should be common sense.

Comment: Still no sign of a [mcve], which makes this question of *very* limited value at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `instanceof` which checks the class of an object. Its syntax is `object instanceof class`.

In your example:

```
if (item instanceof Interact){
    Interact interactItem = (Interact)item;
    interactItem.interact();
    .....
}
```

Comment: The instance of doesn't seem to be working when using an interface.

Comment: "returns false" and "doesn't work" isn't exactly the same.